# Is there a non-loop way to find values within a range and then append the data from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I'm working on a project where I've created bins based on certain values. I would have 2 list of values `x`,`y`. For example: `[100, 102, 104, 106]` and `[2600, 18000, 12000, 4000]` If I choose a bin size of 1 for example I would create a binlist with values `[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]`. For each bin I want to find if a value of `x` falls between there and append the according `y` value. If an `x` value does not fall within this range I want to assign a value of 0. The two lists would like this. `x = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]` and `y = [2600, 0, 18000, 0, 1200, 0, 4000]`.

Currently I use the current code using for loops to check all the bins to all these `x` values as follows:

```
spectrumcounter = 0
binintensitylist = [[] for x in range(len(intensitylist))]
for i in range(len(intensitylist)):
    for bin1 in bins:
        intensity_tmp = 0
        for mz,intensity in zip(mzlist[spectrumcounter],intensitylist[spectrumcounter]):
            if bin1 < mz < bin1 + binwidth:
                intensity_tmp += intensity
        binintensitylist[i].append(intensity_tmp)
    spectrumcounter += 1
```

Here the `x` values are the `mz` and the intensity are the `y` values. Considering I currently use a bin size of 0,01 and have `mz`'s ranging from 100 to sometimes 1600 the amount of bins can be quite large which makes the code really slow using for loops. I've been trying to find a pandas way to resolve this issue but I'm quite new to coding and haven't been able to figure this out myself.

Comment: Have you considered [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) ? The generated keys will be the bins that have values and every number/key that is not present in the counter will have a value of 0

Comment: To get more concrete answers, I would suggest showing sample inputs and the results obtained in your question. This will give folks something to use for testing their own code.